# Summed multiplication of elements for all pairs of variables in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector, algebra

Is their any BASE function other than `crossprod` to simply do `(.1*.3)+(.2*.4)` and output `.11` for my data.frame below?

NOTE: This is a toy example, the data.frame can have any number of columns.

```
x = data.frame(a = c(.1, .2), b = c(.3, .4))

# Desired Output
(.1*.3)+(.2*.4) #= .11

crossprod(as.matrix(x))

# Current output
     a    b
a 0.05 0.11
b 0.11 0.25
```

Comment: What do you want it to do if there are more columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce`

```
c(Reduce(`%*%`, x))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
c(do.call("%*%", x))

[1] 0.11
```

or even

```
x$a%*%x$b
```

Answer (score 1):

if `x` is a `data.frame` as you have shown, you may also do this math in `tidyverse`

```
x %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(c = prod(c_across(everything()))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(c = sum(c)) %>% 
  pull(c)

[1] 0.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
> sum(do.call("*", x))
[1] 0.11
```